# knitr::kable is adding an empty column at the beginning of the table

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I have the following code in a R Markdown document

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
s <- summary(indf)
knitr::kable(na.omit(s[,c(1,2)]))
```
````

The result is:

[image]

How can I remove the extra empty column at the beginning?

I am compiling to ioslides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, kable adds row names.  Trying setting row.names to FALSE:

```
knitr::kable(na.omit(s[,c(1,2)]), row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the rownames from the data frame.

```
s <- summary(indf)
rownames(s) <- NULL
knitr::kable(na.omit(s[,c(1,2)]))
```